# Play headers scala version 2

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I have a play application where I would like to accept custom headers in controller actions.
How does one look up a custom header element in a controller method(action)? I'm coming from ruby rails/sinatra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write an action like:

```
val echo = Action { request =>
  Ok("Got request [" + request + "]")
}
```

`request` is of type `Request` and has a field `headers: Headers` which works pretty much like a `Map`. You can access all the headers that were sent with this object.